Slurp pages with useBackgroundQuery in Apollo Client
A component needs to fetch all data from a paginated GrapQl API. I'd like to use Suspend to suspend the component until all data has been fetched. Here's a query
query Get($first: Int!, $after: String) {
  entity(first: $first, after: $after) {
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage
      endCursor
    }
    { edges { node { id } } }
  }
}

I can trigger it with
const [queryRef, { fetchMore }] = useBackgroundQuery<GetQuery, GetQueryVariables>(…);

And then read the query ref for the first page
const { data: { entity: { pageInfo: { hasNextPage, endCursor} } } } = useReadQuery(queryRef);

fetchMore is a promise. I guess I could just stick it in a useEffect?
useEffect(() => {
  if (hasNextPage && endCursor) {
    void fetchMore({variables: { after: endCursor} });
  }
},[endCursor, hasNextPage, fetchMore]);

How can I avoid that data is defined and React renders the component right before the useEffect is triggered again? Except, perhaps, by checking whether there's hasNextPage and bailing on the render with return null or so. Though that would/could make the skeleton/loading indicator flicker between pages, perhaps?
